# If $\mathscr{U}$ is any point finite cover of $X$, then $\mathscr{U}$ has an irreducible subcover

Tags: general-topology

**Proposition** If $\mathscr{U}$ is any point finite cover of $X$, then $\mathscr{U}$ has an irreducible subcover $\mathscr{V}$, i.e. no proper subcollection of $\mathscr{V}$ covers $X$.

I understand that a collection of open subsets $\mathscr{U}$ is **point finite** if every $x \in X$ is contained in only finitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$.

So suppose $\mathscr{U}$ is a point finite cover of $X$. Then, naturally, $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ since each member of $\mathscr{U}$ is open. By assumption, we also know that

$$\forall \, x \in X, |\{U \in \mathscr{U}: x \in U\}| < \infty$$

Toward a contradiction, suppose that there is a proper subcollection $\mathscr{V}$ that covers $X$. From here, I note a few things:

1.) $\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover.

2.) Since $\mathscr{U}$ is point finite, then since $\mathscr{V} \subset \mathscr{U}$, $\mathscr{V}$ is point finite

3.) Since $\mathscr{V}$ is proper, there exists $U_0 \in \mathscr{U} \setminus \mathscr{V}$.

Can anyone let me know if I'm on the right track? I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Is this *your* proposition, or is it from a book / a known theorem?

Comment: Do you know how to use Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252144/does-every-cover-have-an-irredundant-subcover)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95668/compact-space-locally-finite-subcover/95687#95687)

Comment: @Ulli the second link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95668/compact-space-locally-finite-subcover/95687#95687 utilizes chains and Zorn's lemma, which I am not heavily familiar with. Is there a way of showing this using more elementary methods?

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's from Willard

Comment: @Tyrone Not quite, no

Comment: @David C. Huang: I'm pretty sure that Zorn's lemma or, equivalently, axiom of choice or well-ordering principle is necessary for the proof. At least some weaker version thereof. To proof *this*, however, would involve some advanced techniques. But if you are interested in point-set topology, I recommend to get familiar with (ZL) anyway, since it, or its equivalent formulations, are around in topology almost everywhere.